# Maintain table structures in sync MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my database I have `entries` table and `entriesarchive` table. I will archive the old entries every month I will be altering columns in entries tables.

I want same to be performed on `entriesarchive` table automatically or will stop user to alter entries till he made the change first to `entriesarchive` table as `entries` will be live table every one takes care of it very well.

Is to possible to maintain table structures in sync in MySql?